# Text flickering when receiving data from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Why is it that when the text with the number of digits is displayed, flickering begins, but if you remove `if self.data.data != nil {Text("\(data.data.like)")}` the flickering stops, but then I stop seeing the number of digits, is there a way to display the text differently?
[image]

The text with the number of likes I get from the Firestore database

```
import Firebase

struct Datas {
    var like: NSNumber
}

class getData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: Datas!
    
    init() {
        updateData()
    }
    
    func updateData() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("Like").document("Option").getDocument { (snap, err) in
            
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            let like = snap?.get("ss") as! NSNumber
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data = Datas(like: like)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

CellLike.swift

```
struct CellLike: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var data = getData()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            /// Like Button
            
            if self.data.data != nil {
            /// Number Like
                Text("\(data.data.like)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Change the ObservedObject to a StateObject

Comment: @loremipsum But if I change to `StateObject` then the number is not updated in real time, the data is updated only after restarting the application

Comment: `getDocument` doesn't return real-time updates. That's what `addSnapshotListener` is for: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: That means something else is wrong, it is unsafe to initialize with `@ObservedObject` it is for passing around.  Basically the only reason it updates is because of a bug/malfunction, you need snapshot listener

Comment: It looks like it's "real-time" right now because `init` runs on every re-render and gets new data from Firestore -- basically a "polling" mechanism. It's not actually getting data "pushed" from the server.

Comment: @jnpdx Well, you know what I'm trying to achieve, I'm already asking 3 questions, and my attempts are not very successful, is it difficult for you to help show how to implement it? you send me documentation, but I can't implement it because I'm learning and don't know many things

Comment: Like I said, you need to use `addSnapshotListener` -- did you try that? I sent you the link to the documentation, which has an example in Swift.

Comment: @jnpdx I think I did it! Thanks

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you very much! I also wanted to ask you, perhaps you know this, is there a monetary fee for requesting this data if an application is put into production? Or are these other cases?

Comment: Firebase has quite extensive documentation on their billing. The free plan is pretty generous.